# Dynamically bind datasource for multiple Kendo ComboBoxes

Tags: jquery, performance, combobox, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a page which is having almost 100 KendoComboBoxes, each having different datasources. I want each combobox to be binded to respective datasource by using ".BindTo(Model.Attribute.Value)".

PFB my cshtml code:

```
 @Html.FormRow().AddContent(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                        .Enable(true)
                        .Name(ViewData["EnumAttrHierarchicalName"] + ".Attribute.WritedValue")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new
                        {
                            formedit = formEditVal
                        })
                        .Filter(FilterType.Contains)                  
                        .DataTextField("Text")
                        .DataValueField("Value")
                        .BindTo(Model.Attribute.Value)
                        .AutoBind(true)
                        .Value(Model.Attribute.WritedValue)
                        )

***Script 1:***
<script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[formedit]").kendoComboBox();
        });
</script>

***Script 2:***
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('input[formedit]').each(function () {
             if ($(this).attr('formedit') == '') return;

             dropDownItems = $('#hidden' + $(this).attr('formedit')).val();
             var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
             {
                 data: JSON.parse(dropDownItems),
                 dataType: "json"
             });

             $(this).kendoComboBox({
                 dataTextField: "Text",
                 dataValueField: "Value",
                 dataSource: sharedDataSource,
                 filter: "contains",
                 placeholder: "Please Select...",
                 suggest: true
            });

         });
     });
<script>
```

If I use "Script 1", I am not getting data into my combobox. Whereas if I use "Script 2" its taking so much time for the page to be rendered.

Can anyone please let me know the optimal solution for this issue.